# FLOSS tool to convert single page MATLAB PDF graphics to PDF/A on Linux

Tags: open-source, pdf, document-converter, archiving, matlab

What software can save a MATLAB figure to a PDF/A (PDF/A-1b would be fine) compatible file with export_fig?

The generation of PDF/A compatible files should be done with MATLAB and FLOSS tool(s) on a Linux system.

It is fine for me to check the output manually.

Comment: My former colleagues who were using Matlab were generally exporting the figure in latex/tikz, and then were using latex to generate pdf. Fast, free, and easy, ... if you know latex.